# RegEx to accept 6 or 7 and then only an additional 9 or 10 numbers

Tags: regex

tax

V1

```
/([67]\d{10})|([67]\d{9})/
```

V2

```
/[67]\d{9,10}/
```

RegexBuddy highlights the second and third test records, but also portions of the first and last.

```
6777777777777777777
6777777777
7777777777
77777777777777
```

Is it possible to only match the exact matches?

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific, about your input.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [anchors `^` and `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to match the start and end of the string/line:

```
^[67]\d{9,10}$
```

Or `\b` to mark the [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b[67]\d{9,10}\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try matching word boundaries.

```
\<[67][0-9]\{9,10\}\>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should have included some information about the context in which you're using the regexp, but the common way is to include boundary matchers:

```
^[67]\d{9,10}$
```

Answer (score 1):

What's separating your numbers? You can use a word boundary like this:

> `\b[67]\d{9,10}\b`

Or whitespace, like this

> `\s[67]\d{9,10}\s`